# how to solve undefined variable error in compact() function?

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

I want to send email with some information. That's why I use `compact()` function within `view()` function. But I got an error 'undefined variable':

```
public $message_to_send="";
public $first_name_to_send="";

public function __construct($first_name,$message) {
    $this->message_to_send=$message;
    $this->first_name_to_send=$first_name;
}

public function build(){
    return $this->view('email/contactmessageemail',compact('message_to_send','first_name_to_send'));
}
```

The error message is:

> compact(): Undefined variable: message_to_send

Answer (score 2):

try to edit it to

```
view('email.contactmessageemail',[
   'message_to_send' => $this->message_to_send,
   'first_name_to_send' => $this->first_name_to_send
]);
```

`compact` didn't work in your case because the variables that you want to pass in is not locally defined in the method scope it is declared as a public property

Comment: (You had an extra `'` in there, edited it out for you)

Comment: @joseph your answer didn't work at all,I got an error message  ''Invalid view.'

Comment: "Invalid View"  @ joseph, Do i need to add return before your answer??

Comment: i find it you write `return view('email/contactmessageemail')` but it should be `return view('email.contactmessageemail')` you need to add ***.*** instead of ***/***

Answer (score 1):

This was a breaking changed introduced in PHP 7.3 with `compact()`.  Previously, you could send through undefined variables with `compact()`, but now it flags as an error.

`compact()` is still a fantastic method - but you will need to define the variables within the method that you are using it.  To keep code clean and readable, I suggest you define the variables and then pass using `compact()` as you had originally intended.

So you can fix using the original code like this:

```
public function build(){
    $message_to_send = $this->message_to_send;
    $first_name_to_send = $this->first_name_to_send;
    return view('email.contactmessageemail',compact('message_to_send','first_name_to_send'));
}
```

Note I removed `$this` from the view call.

You can also always pass the variables right into the `build()` method - which is sort of the norm - then you don't have to define within the method.

Comment: Thanks. Finally you saved me. But this also works just declare as         
         global $message_to_send;
        global $first_name_to_send;  in build function.

Comment: Yes, that will work too.  But to keep clean and within your original bounds, you may wish to do it within the convention in the answer above.

Comment: I marked the answer as accepted but my reputaion is very low and i am new to stack overflow

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful.  If you would like to mark it as accepted, just click the check box right below the voting arrows on my answer